# Determine and Change Office 2010 Culture?

Tags: c#, reflection, ms-office, culture

I'm writing a business program for a hospital. In that every user should use specific culture and datetime witch is updated from the server. it is not VSTO app so i use Process class and track process name to detect an office program such as word have run and i want to change datetime and culture for this process i know maybe i could use a better approach but for some reason i have to do it in this way.

So i want to know does Microsoft Office has APIs for solving this solution or is there any suggestion for using reflection